# How to split a string column into 2 strings( after second comma)

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

So I was wondering how can I split the strinf column into 2 columns, but not after I come across first comma, but second.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'Address': ["Berlin, 842, 05", "Vienna, 810, 00", "Moscow, 820, 00"]})

data[["city", "code"]] = data["Address"].str.split(",", n= 2, expand = True)
data
```

```
So I would want something like
City                 Code
Berlin, 842         05
Vienna, 810         00
Moscow, 820         00
```

Comment: The expected output is unclear (do you want to drop a chunk? split only once?). Please provide it

Comment: o I would want something like in city column :    Berlin, 842    and in code column 05, so I want to split column into 2 but after second comma

Answer (score 2):

`n` denotes the number of splits, not the number of output columns. You should use `n=1`. Also, use `rsplit`:

```
data[['city', 'code']] = data['Address'].str.rsplit(',', n=1, expand=True)
```

output:

```
             Address            city     code
0   Mojkovac,842, 05   Mojkovac, 842       05
1  Podgorica,810, 00  Podgorica, 810       00
2    Kolasin,820, 00    Kolasin, 820       00
```

If you further want to remove the comma in city

```
data['city'] = data['city'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: But I want for example in first column to be  Mojkovac 842   and in second 05, so basically I want to split it after second comma.

Comment: Ok, then use `rsplit`